# how the following ways of selection differs from each other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose I want  to select $2$ elements out of $6$ elements. Then I get $6C2 = 15$ combinations. Here $C$ represents the standard formula of ($N C R$). Now my question is what  differences arise when we try to do the job in two tasks like  first I choose $1$ element out of $6$ by $6C1$ and then $1$ among the remaining $5$ by $5C1$. The total combination becomes $6C1 \cdot 5C1 = 30$, which are not the same. I don't understand where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For the second case, the order of the first task and the task chosen matters. If we want to get rid of the order, divide it by $2!$.

$$\binom{6}{2}= \frac{6!}{4!2!}$$

Comment: ok, i understood but i have i more question. what happens when we get to the generalisation of it . like i want to choose 3 objects out of 6 , which can be done by taking 3 at once , or (2,1) , (1,2) or (1,1,1) . now what should we have to do , by your assertion i get that we need to divide by the factorial of number of subtasks  of the task to remove the permutation caused by the using different subtasks. is that correct

Comment: yes, that is how combinations and permutations are related.

Comment: @RajendraBalliwal If you take $3$ at once, you cannot obtain $(2, 1)$, $(1, 2)$, or $(1, 1, 1)$.  Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Taussig is right. those are not achievable, we can have $(1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), (3,2,1)$ but since the order doesn't matter, we divide by $3!$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh i think you got me wrong somewhere , by (1,2)i was saying that first i choose 1 element out 6 then 2 elements from the remaining 5 . but i have calculated that they are not equal if i divide the later procedure of (1,2) by 2! , that being said , i think choosing of task should be done at once else it may result in some unconcerning problem , am i correct?

Comment: If you want to do $(1,2)$, there are $3$ ways to distinguish those sets at the last position, hence divide by $3$. but yup, don't do stuff that confuses yourself.

Answer (score 1):

By first method you calculate the cardinality of $\{\{i,j\}\mid (i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\text{ and }i\neq j\}$.

By second method you calculate the cardinality of $\{(i,j)\mid (i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\text{ and }i\neq j\}$.

Note that e.g. $\{3,4\}=\{4,3\}$ but $(3,4)\neq(4,3)$.

---

**Edit**:

Applying the first method you find an answer on the question:

> How many subsets of exactly $2$ elements has the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Applying the second method you find an answer on the question:

> How many ordered pairs $(i,j)$ are there if it is demanded that $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $i\neq j$?

Comment: i am sorry but can you simplify what you are saying, in simple words

Comment: I have edited my answer.